# Image dataset for pomegranate plant disease

Tags: machine-learning, image-recognition, datasets, image-processing

I am implementing a project on pomegranate plant disease in Machine learning. I want a dataset of all kind images of a healthy and unhealthy part of the pomegranate plant. I got a dataset from Fruit360 but that is only for pomegranate fruits but need for leaves also. Is there anyone who knows any website, link, version control system repository and/or any resource from which I get a dataset for leaves.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the dataset in the following links:

- [Pomegranate Disease Detection Using Image Processing](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S187705091502133X)
- [fruits 360 datasets](https://www.kaggle.com/moltean/fruits)

Comment: Thank for your reply but this dataset only for fruits if you get a dataset for leaves, please suggest

Comment: Have you checked the first link?